# How can I input in console without changing what's already shown? [C++]

Tags: c++, input, console, iostream

I want to input something ([PLAYER NAME]) in console:

```
|=========[ Player Creation ]=========|
|Player name: [PLAYER NAME]           |
|=====================================|
```

But as you might know, there are some problems:

1. The third line is not shown until I input the name.
2. The last vertical line in the second line is not shown until I input the player's name. And after inputting the name, it will be misplaced.

How could I enter the player's name, while showing the entirety of the menu.

```
void playerMenu(std::string playerName) {
std::cout <<
    "|=========[ Player Creation ]=========|\n"
    "|Player name:";
std::cin >> playerName;
std::cout <<
    "|\n"
    "|=====================================|";
}
```

Comment: This goes above and beyond what `cout` can provide. You need to use a textual UI library such as ncurses or tickit.

Comment: That will depend on your console. You may have to use a library like ncurses to do that or an OS API if you are on MSWindows (which you did not mention so we can't assume).

Comment: Plain C++ does not allow you to jump around with the cursor on the screen. However, most platforms provide extensions which allows you to do this. Therefore, for your question to be answerable, please specify to which platform (i.e. operating system) your question applies.

Comment: On Linux/Unix use the ncurses library, on Windows use the Console API

Comment: The standard I/O model is pretty much based on the teletypes/teleprinters used in the Olden Days.( I think "typewriter that you and the computer can take turns to write on" is a reasonable description.) If you want something more advanced than "simulated paper", you need to use some kind of library.

Comment: On Microsoft Windows, you can use the function [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to jump around with the cursor on the screen, or you can also use [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) on Windows 10 or higher.

Comment: Assuming you are using the Amiga operating system, you can use ANSI sequences.